# condition_variable::notify_one does not instantly unblock wait?

Tags: c++, mutex, condition-variable

I have a question about the notify_one function. At the following code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>

std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex m;
bool ready = false;

void f()
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
  std::cout << "get into wait, ready=" << ready << std::endl;
  cv.wait(lk, []() { return ready; });
  std::cout << "get out of wait, ready=" << ready << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  std::thread a(f);

  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m, std::defer_lock);
    if (lk.try_lock()) {
      std::cout << "main try_lock success, ready=" << ready << std::endl;
      ready = true;
    }
  }
  std::cout << "main notify, ready=" << ready << std::endl;
  cv.notify_one();

  // std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;

  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m, std::defer_lock);
    if (lk.try_lock()) {
      std::cout << "main try_lock success, ready=" << ready << std::endl;
      ready = true;
    }
  }
  std::cout << "main notify, ready=" << ready << std::endl;
  cv.notify_one();

  a.join();

  return 0;
}
```

I get a following result,

```
get into wait, ready=0
main try_lock success, ready=0
main notify, ready=1
main try_lock success, ready=1
main notify, ready=1
get out of wait, ready=1
```

But I expect a below result, because, according to the [page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait), if notify_one is called wait is unblocked and lock of mutex(m) is reacquired.

```
get into wait, ready=0
main try_lock success, ready=0
main notify, ready=1
main notify, ready=1
get out of wait, ready=1
```

I found if I comment out the `std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;` I get expected result. Looks to me like notify_one does not immediately unblock the wait. It is correct?

Thank you very much!

Comment: _Looks to me like notify_one does not immediately unblock the wait._ It's actually the responsibility of the OS scheduler to start (aka. resume) threads. `notify_one()` may signal another thread that it _can_ be executed but the scheduler decides when it _will_ be executed. Relying onto "immediately" sounds somehow too optimistic to me.

Comment: I wonder if the wake up is atomic with the locking of the mutex. If it's not, then that's another way how it can go wrong. (If the mutex cannot be locked after wakeup, the `condition_variable` implementation needs to atomically put it back to sleep, though.)

Comment: From a very superficial glance, it looks like the underlying futex mechanism on Linux will indeed _not_ perform an atomic (wakeup + locking). So after wakeup but before locking, the mutex can be locked by your main thread.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone!. I understand there is no guarantee of immediate unblocking and locking. And another thing, unblocking and locking don't arise simultaneously. I feel it's not simple to use, but my problem is solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Looks to me like notify_one does not immediately unblock the wait. It is correct?

Notification immediately *unblocks* the wait, meaning the wait is *able* to resume after the notification. That is, the sleeping thread is marked as runnable.

However, the scheduler doesn't necessarily re-start it immediately. If it would have to pre-empt some already running thread/process, it will probably wait until a yield, a syscall or some other cancellation point, and otherwise not even look at the newly-runnable thread until the end of the current timeslice.

Unblocking something is not the same as forcing an immediate context switch (which is lucky, as otherwise synchronization would be even more expensive).

Comment: 'will probably wait until a yield, a syscall or some other cancellation point, and otherwise not even look at the newly-runnable thread until the end of the current timeslice' why would the scheduler/dispatcher do that?  The notify syscall has already entered the kernel and so there is no good reason to defer making the notified thread running 'immediately' if a core is available to run it, or very soon after if the scheduler needs to free up a core that is running another thread.  Always waiting for a timer interrupt would just introduce avoidably poor performance:(

Comment: You could absolutely do that on a platform with sufficiently cheap context switches and no CPU cache. On most real-world systems the crippling performance cost of your version will count as quite a good reason, actually.

Comment: Well, typically, setting a thread running upon an inter-thread signal takes less than 5us, if a core is available.  Always waiting for a timer interrupt would intruduce a crippling, average latency of half a tick to inter-thread comms, making many apps infeasible, eg video streaming, bitTorrent and many apps I have myself developed.

Comment: If a core is idle, sure, but context-switching the notifying thread for the notified one means parking something that may still have work to do, and which is likely to be already in cache (and has a warm branch predictor, etc.) If you want to do that, you can explicitly yield, but I'd be surprised if that were the default behaviour. Apart from anything else, it's perfectly legal to release the mutex _after_ signalling, and this would be a disaster in your version.

Answer (score 2):

After your first `cv.notify_one();` you have no synchronization points (until `a.join();`) and the thread already running will most likely continue to run and reach `a.join();` before the scheduler decides to give the other thread a spin.

As an experiment, you can yield the thread's execution slot by sleeping a little after notifying - and it *may* cause the order of the output to be what you expected.

```
cv.notify_one();
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
```

Don't rely on it in production code though. This doesn't guarantee anything since there is no synchronization between the threads (other than the `join()`).